# How to manage different form views based on access and column value

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I am facing and problem that I would like to solve using laravel. I want to make items in the system with several columns. Once this item reaches specified status and is pending at specific user it can be edited. However there will be many edit views based on access rights and statuses. What is the best way to solve this via laravel?

I had these suggestions:

1. Solve this within middleware during calling the edit method
2. Solve this within several @if @else commands in edit.blade.php file
3. Solve this via many different routes and methods and many views

What i would like to achieve is that if proper users opens the edit link proper view is loaded and if not then user is redirected to some kind of "no acces" page or simple display view.

Comment: This sounds like two problems. Where a user should not have access to edit a page, then I think this should be handled with middleware or a policy. Where the edit capabilities differ depending on user authorisation, I would determine the correct template/partial for the given user, and then simply load that. You'd also need to perform the same checks when validating the form submission to ensure only the appropriate fields can be edited by each user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So would you create different request files as well or you would you handle the field validation based on if statements within rules method?

Comment: That's difficult to answer. I would make the decision based on how much they differ from one another. Another option might be to extend one Request file from the other to keep things DRY.